# Is there a good API for google play and/or Apple store to retrieve comments and ratings of Apps in their markets?

Tags: api, google-play, app-store, google-play-developer-api

I have found no official one, and the ones I have found are either of payment or not very good. Anyone knows of a good API for google play / apple store?

Many Thanks!

Laura.